# Does reification of scala expressions work in v2.9?

Tags: scala, expression, reification

I was playing around with scala lifting and I accidentally discovered that Scala seems has some sort of implicit support for lambda expressions.

```
import scala.reflect.Code
import scala.reflect.Function
import scala.reflect.Select

object Test {
  trait Foo {
    def aMethod : String
  }

  val ast : Code[_] = (f:Foo) => f.aMethod 

  //now you can pattern match the AST 
  val Function(_, Select(_, symbol))= ast.tree
  val nameOfAMethod = symbol.name
  println(nameOfAMethod) //prints "aMethod"
}
```

ast will have the AST for the lambda on the right hand side.

It seems not to work for literals, so:

```
val ast : Code[_] = 42
```

does not work.

But this does :

```
val ast : Code[_] = () => 42
```

I can't seem to find documentation for it. There doesn't seem to be any implicit conversion active. How does this work?

Comment: You must be missing something because on my side it won't compile. That's assuming `trait Code[T]`. It could be some custom implicits in your code that were doing this conversion for you.

Comment: Please please please mention your imports.

Comment: @NikitaVolkov I think he means `scala.reflect.Code`.

Comment: The source for `Code` says `/** This type is required by the compiler and <b>should not be used in client code</b>. */`. So it looks like some kind of special case for the compiler. I would not worry about it and follow the advice that you should not use it.

Comment: I'm not worried about it. I like it! It's like Expression<> in C# ;)

Comment: 2.10 will contain a full(er) reflection API (behind an experimental flag). RC1 for that may be as soon as next week.  You might like to try it out.

Comment: Yes, we will be upgrading to 2.10 at some point. In the mean time we're using scala.reflect._ w